# How to make a command that adds a role to a specific user for a certain amount of time? (Discord.js v12 ONLY)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm looking for a way to make a command to add a role (lets just say Moderator) till a certain date.... command would look something like the following..

`.addrole @Cylence#0001 834130492219588671 07/20/21`

this would use a `mm/dd/yy` format and remove the role once that date comes around...I'm new to discord.js and js in general and I have 0 clue where to start looking so I thought I'd ask here! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way would be to create a database and connect it to your Discord Bot, for example **MongoDB**, **mySQL**, etc.

*Just choose one and google how to implement that*

If you have done this, you could save that **date** together with e.g. the **user ID** and the **role (ID)** to your **database**

The last thing you'd need is an "**event**" you have to create for yourself. You may check the current date every day and look up in the database if there are roles, that have to be removed today. In this case you can remove the role again.

*Again, just google it if you dont know to to set this up*

---

There may be shorter, faster solutions to solve this, but this one would be my attempt :D